# how to hide all other tabs except first tab in jquery when using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am making a web app in Eclipse, using JSP, CSS, JQUERY(jquery-1.10.2.js) and AJAX. I have made a tab effect using HTML(actually JSP) and CSS.
I have 2 JSP files:

- 1st JSP (named: `home.jsp`) file has only 1 button which will load the content of second JSP file using AJAX      (Jquery load() method).
- 2nd JSP (named: `second.jsp`) file has actual HTML for tab effect.

Problem is I am unable to show the first tab and hide rest of others. Whats happening is that all the panels(divs) to which the tabs are linked are shown one after the other.

I also want to tell, that problem is fixed when I click any one of them(tabs)..i.e when I click any 1 tab rest of others get hide.

But what i want is that when my `second.jsp` file is loaded using `ajax`, I got to see only first tab panel not other by default.

Actually, I am unable to post images due to my low reputation..but to have a clear view of my problem you can watch the video at YOUTUBE at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=useXgTzEAZg

Following is the file wise code:

### `home.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
#homeDiv {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px:
}
</style>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jkl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#but').click(function() {
            $('#homeDiv').load('folder2/second.jsp #main');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="but">press</button>
    <br>
    <div id="homeDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### `second.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>News Headlines</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>...</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="main">
                <script src="js/jkl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <h1>Tabbed Panels</h1>
                <div class="tabbedPanels" id="tabbed1">

                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <li><a href="#panel1" tabindex="1">Tab 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#panel2" tabindex="2">Tab 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#panel3" tabindex="3">Tab 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panelContainer">
                        <div id="panel1" class="panel">
                            <h2>Panel 1 content</h2>
                            <p>Apples</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="panel2" class="panel">
                            <h2>Panel 2 content</h2>
                            <p>Mango</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="panel3" class="panel">
                            <h2>Panel 3 content</h2>
                            <p>Potato</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### `jkl.js (JavaScript file)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert('outside');
    //$('.tabs a').bind('click focus',function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.tabs a', function()
                {
        var $this = $(this);
        //alert('?????');
        // hide panels
        $this.parents('.tabbedPanels')
            .find('.panel').hide().end()
            .find('.active').removeClass('active');

        // add active state to new tab
        $this.addClass('active').blur();    

        // retrieve href from link (is id of panel to display)
        var panel = $this.attr('href');
        // show panel
        $(panel).show();
        // don't follow link
        return false;
    }); // end click

    $('.tabs').find('li:first a').click();
}); // end ready
```

### `styles.css`

```
.tabbedPanels {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
.tabs {
    margin: 20;
    padding: 20;    
    zoom : 1;
}
.tabs li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
}
.tabs a {


    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    /* background-color: red;; */
    margin-right: 1px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100,20,135);
    margin-bottom: -2px;
    width: 60px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:8px;

}
.tabs .active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

.panelContainer {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 25px;    
    border: 1px solid red;  
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

.panel h2 {
    color: red;
    text-shadow: none;      
}
.panel p {
    color: black;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve this, I gave the ID to first tab `<a id='first_a'>` in `second.jsp` file.

then replace the script in `home.jsp` to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#but').click(function() {
            $('#homeDiv').load('folder2/second.jsp #main', function() {
                $('#first_a').click();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```